# Message box doesnt work after changing text?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I wanted to change the text of the message box from "Are you sure ...?" to "You're information is ready to be submitted" When I did this using the code below the message box no longer works. Does this code rely on the "Are you sure" portion?

```
 Try
        Dim msg As String = "Hello!"
        Dim script As String = "if(confirm('You're information is ready to be submitted')) {window.location.href ='frmMain.aspx'; }"
        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me, Me.[GetType](), "Test", script, True)
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The apostrophe in " You're " needs to be escaped. Replace " You're " with " You\'re ".

Edit: A good point was brought up in the comments - grammatically, it should be " Your ".

Comment: I was just about to edit it to say this: I realized that too late.